# C# form class extension issue

Tags: c#, winforms

My current Form1.cs is being too big so I'm trying to break them up into multiple smaller files so the codes are easier to read.  However, my method of doing works for what I need but also annoying at the same time because each one of my extension is being treated as a form.  So if I double-click on the extension a form popups instead of the class.  So I have to keep clicking then press F7.  Please advise a workaround

Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            test();
        }
    }
}
```

Form1_Ext.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 
    {
        public void test()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hello");
        }
    }
}
```

Form1.Desginer.cs

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.Text = "Form1";
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

[image]

Please see the red box, any extension class is being treated as a form of its own instead of being a class.  At min it should point to Form1.cs but it isn't.

Comment: These are not called extensions, they are partial classes, you're splitting the definition up. The reason for your issue is because any part that declares a base type, then the whole type inherits that class. In your specific case it is `Form`.

Comment: I voted to reopen this question.  It's poorly phrased, but it's a valid question.  The question is basically: How can I create files containing `partial class` implementations of my Windown Forms form class and have them a) appear related to the main Form definition file and b) open using the default code editor rather than the form editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are asking.  However, if you want to split your Form's code up into multiple files by using the `partial` keyword on the `Form1` class and have each of the files appear to be a child of the Form1 entry in the *Solution Explorer* tree, you need to hand edit the *WindowsFormsApplication2.csproj* file.  Before you do that, make sure you back it up (it's easy to break your project if don't know what you are doing).

If you look at the file, you will see something like this:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Form1.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Form1.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Form1_Ext.cs" />
    <!-- More entries -->
  </ItemGroup>
```

What you want to do is make "Form1_Ext.cs" *DependentUpon* the main form entry.  So change:

```
<Compile Include="Form1_Ext.cs" />
```

to:

```
<Compile Include="Form1_Ext.cs">
  <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

I think that's what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I was looking for.  So now Form1_Ext.cs is a child of Form1.cs, Form1_Ext is still being treated as form instead of a class.  How do I go about disabling it so VS will open as a class whenever I double-click?

Comment: I don't know - I've never done what you are trying to do.  However, if you consider the _Form1.Designer.cs_ file, it effectively has a file extension of ".Designer.cs".  Maybe if picked an extension for your extra files (Form1_Ext.Partial.cs), then right-clicked, picked "Open With" and then choose "C# Editor" and clicked "Set As Default" it might work.

Comment: @Syntax_MM: If my suggestion works, let me know. I'll add it to my answer

Comment: @Syntax_MM: I created a test WinForms project, added a new file (named Form1Extra.Partial.cs), put some `partial class Form1` code in it and then fiddled with the csproj file so that it now looks like `<Compile Include="Form1Extra.Partial.cs"> <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon> <SubType>Form</SubType> </Compile>`.  I believe it _just works_ the way you want it (it shows up under `Form1` in the Solution Explorer tree, and double clicking opens the code editor, not the form editor.

Comment: Yep I got <SubType>Form</SubType> </Compile> added, confirmed this is the issue I keep stumping on.  VS won't autogen this xml syntax for designer but it will autogen for form extensions.  How do I go about preventing MS from adding this wrapper: <SubType>Form</SubType> </Compile> since it won't let me delete?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have already solved it. If you're interested, this code seems to work:

```
<Compile Include="Form1.Extra.Designer.cs"><DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

Apparently, you need to use the "Designer" keyword.

Bye.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76312063/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).